# Why do some moderators consider a Raspberry Pi to be a toy? I have used it many times for business

Tags: discussion

I've made one post on this site, which was dismissed, and put on hold as a home/hobby/end user problem, and asked me to have it moved to the Raspberry Pi sibling site.

Frankly, not wanting to dismiss the Pi subsite, I don't think that most located there, have relevance to a business to business IPSEC wan scenario for mailbox replication.  It's not a home project.

The Pi devices have many places of use in small to medium businesses keeping costs low as standby DNS and MX servers.

The problem I described was not even with the Pi, but the Xeon x64 server, in the data centre 850 miles away.

Why do some moderators have a problem with this?

It seems that "Raspbian" is a tag for an instant downvote.

This is making me feel unwelcome.  I've put good input in, and I get treated like trash by a snob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything Sven said is true in general, but in this case I'm willing to accept that it's not a Home Use question and I've re-opened the question so you can post an answer.

As you become more familiar with Stackexchange, you'll see that putting questions on hold or closing them doesn't carry any implication that you're not good enough, it simply means that the question didn't fit.  Updating the question, commenting, and/or asking on meta is sometimes necessary to make a question fit.

Comment: My question was not about the Pi.  The Pi is just a casual participant as a "Proof of Concept".  Perhaps I tagged it wrongly.

Answer (score 14):

First of all: I love my RPi collection. I run nearly half a dozen of them. At home.

For work: We (the majority of the active community on this site) absolutely insists on a professional approach to running business applications and in our view, trying this on RPi like devices doesn't fit this description.

This is due to the severe limitations of the RPi hardware that makes them simply unsuitable for a reliable deployment in a business context. Before I would even consider to use an RPi for such cases, I would take a very hard look at small instance sizes of cloud or VPS providers where I can run a system in a **much** more reliable way for a few dollars per month and have redundant power supplies and disk subsystems that don't use flaky SD cards and share the same slow USB2 data path with the network interface.

Other sites on the network that can help you better with anything related to the hardware and the specific OS variants running on them, so just use those.

If having disagreeing opinions what is topical here makes you feel unwelcome, then you have to live with that because having that feeling doesn't entitle you to ask questions deemed off-topic by the community. Having a question closed isn't treating you as trash, and having differing opinions doesn't make the other side a snob.